# Powershell code to output azure VM, Name, Resource group, VNET, Subnet and NSG to excel?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Can someone advise how I can output an azure VMS details to an excel file or text file using powershell? I would need the Name of the VM, the VNET, the Subnet and the NSG ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following way to export the VM details to the excel.

```html
$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "test" -Name "testVM"
$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "VM Name" = $_.Name
        "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        "VM Profile" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        "VM OS Disk Size" = $_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.DiskSizeGB
        "VM Data Disk Size" = ($_.StorageProfile.DataDisks.DiskSizeGB) -join ','
    }
}
$vmOutput | export-csv C:\Users\test\vmdata.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

And then you could find the excel in the C:\Users\test\vmdata.csv
[image]